# php how to scan full page for all POST variables and then echo at top of page?

Tags: php, variables, post

I can't echo my variable above my CMS include code.. but if I echo the variable after, then it recognizes the $url variable.

Here is some code:

```
    <?php
    // here is my CMS inlcude code
    $template = 'news_script'; 
    $number = '';
    $category = '';  
    include $cutepath.'/show_news.php'; 

   ?>
```

If I `echo  $url` above the include code, it returns nothing. But below, it obviously recognizes it.

Is there a php function that scans the whole page and retrieves all the POST variables so you can use $url at the top of the php page with a  `header('Location:'. $url);` script??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously `$url` is being defined in your show_news.php script. PHP executes a script line-by-line, and will not magically "reach back" to set a variables value in an earlier line.

Comment: Gotcha. Thought I was missing magic from php ? But I guess not.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another (ugly) way would be:

```
<?php
  // here is my CMS inlcude code
  $template = 'news_script'; 
  $number = '';
  $category = '';  
  ob_start();
  include $cutepath.'/show_news.php'; 
  $buffered_data=ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  echo $url; // here you could place your: header('Location:'. $url);
  echo $buffered_data;
?>
```

Comment: hmm. what is with the $buffered_data ??

Comment: If `show_news.php` outputs something it will be stored in `$buffered_data`, that way you can use your `header()` function, because it requires that no output to the client is made before using it or else you would get the following error: `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`